# WPF - Datagrid get new item AFTER editing

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, caliburn.micro

I'm a little stuck on an issue with WPF datagrids, and once again my google foo has failed me, what i want to do seem very simple but i cant for the life of me work it out.

Please bare in mind that i am using Caliburn Micro for this application

I have a datagrid, which is bound to an `ObservableCollection<Item>` the items themselves handle changes using `NotifyOfPropertyChange` and a **IsDirty** flag, so editing these items is not an issue, however i cannot work out how to handle new items being added, we use the **CanUserEditRows** property of the datagrid to allow inline adding of new items.

However my problem comes when i try and detect a new item being added, in order to fire it off to my database services, it seems many people use the `CollectionChanged` event of the `ObservableCollection` in order to detect this, However this seem to fire the instant the user clicks on the `{NewItemPlaceholder}` part of the datagrid, before any data has been inserted.

```
private void ItemList_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewItems != null)
    {
        foreach (Item i in e.NewItems)
        {
            _itemManager.Insert(i);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code i'm using, perhaps i've made a mistake, but i cant seem to work out how to get this to fire only AFTER the editing has finished, unfortunately google seems to be returning the same results no matter how i try and reword my question. Hopefully someone here can provide me with a relatively simple answer to this question.

If you need more code to show you how things work (such as the `_itemManager`) I can provide if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very simple:

```
// instances of this type user should edit in data grid
public class Item : IEditableObject
{
    // the item identifier
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // some data-bound properties

    #region IEditableObject Members

    public void BeginEdit()
    {            
    }

    public void CancelEdit()
    {
    }

    public void EndEdit()
    {
        // new items has identifier, set to 0
        if (Id == 0)
        {
            // post changes here
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

`DataGrid` knows about [`IEditableObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ieditableobject.aspx), and if the bound data item implements this interface, grid calls corresponding methods during the editing.

Comment: Editing the item is not my problem, Editing is working fine, its the ability to tell when a NEW item has been added to datagrid using the {NewItemPlaceholder} on the datagrid itself, would your solution not fire on every single edit, regardless on if the item is new or not?

Comment: "when a NEW item has been added" - it's trivial, since you should have a criteria for "new item". Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that makes sense however i have a quick question, the CRUD functions are handled by _itemManager in my viewmodel, now i'm considering just having a IsNew property on my object and doing a check the same way i use IsDirty on saving. However i wondered if there was a cleaner way that having to check both isnew and isdirty on each item when it comes to saving the data.

Comment: Are you saving item immediately after editing, or you're using batch update to save multiple items at once?

Comment: I batch save the items, I was planning to add the items immediately after creation, however i have no issues with batch saving, which would be how i used the IsNew property.

Comment: +1 for the right answer.  The datagrid has transaction state awareness and will use the callbacks if the client has implemented editable object.  Not implementing IEditableObject can be  a nasty WPF 'gotcha'

Comment: Personally, I prefer approach with the enum like `ItemState` (`New`, `Dirty`, `Unchanged`) and a single state property in editable item instead of `IsNew` and `IsDirty`.

Comment: Ah, that is a good idea, thanks dennis. I'll have to see if any of the caliburn.micro base classes implement IEditableObject. Thanks again